# Oracle Performance Limitation of SQL UNION query & how to optimize

Tags: java, sql, oracle, query-performance

**story**

I have two codes which perform the same task with the different way.

```
number_of_factors =10
number_of_formula_portions=5
number_of_travellers=15
cycles=2
```

1. call DB multiple times read data =5*15*2 times DB calls. and use ehcache.
2. call DB only 1 time (one query contains 10*5*15*2 of sql union operations in one query)

logically 2nd one should get more performance because of only 1 DB call, time-saving.
But practically 2nd one takes more time to evaluate query.

I have a dynamically generated union query. It has 10*5*15*2 (number_of_factors *number_of_formula_portions*number_of_travellers*number_of_cycles) union statements. When I run it DB is taking too much time. But when I run it for one traveler via the application, It is fine. I thought logically reading all data at once has a lot of performance, But DB is getting stuck.

UNIT QUERY

```
select ? as FACTORNAME,
       WEIGHTING,
       ? as KEYCYCLE,
       ? as KEYTRAVELLER,
       ? as KEYSUBFORMULA
from   (
  (SELECT *
   FROM   (
     (SELECT ID,
             ELEMENT_LOGIC_ID,
             FACTOR_VALUE1,
             FACTOR_VALUE2,
             FACTOR_VALUE3,
             FACTOR_VALUE4,
             FACTOR_VALUE5,
             FACTOR_VALUE6,
             FACTOR_VALUE7,
             WEIGHTING,
             START_DATE,
             END_DATE
     FROM   ABC_PRICE_FACTOR
     WHERE  ELEMENT_LOGIC_ID =?
     AND    START_DATE <= ?
     AND    END_DATE >= ? 
     AND    FACTOR_VALUE1=?
     ORDER BY ID DESC )
   )
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 1)
)
```

PARAMETERS

```
    F577(String), 0(String), 0(String), 1(String), 577(Long), 2018-06-28 00:00:00.0(Timestamp), 2018-06-28 00:00:00.0(Timestamp), 1(String),
```

SAMPLE UNION QUERY

```
    select * from (

     select ? as FACTORNAME,WEIGHTING,? as KEYCYCLE,? as KEYTRAVELLER,? as KEYSUBFORMULA from ( (SELECT * FROM ( (SELECT ID, ELEMENT_LOGIC_ID, FACTOR_VALUE1, FACTOR_VALUE2,FACTOR_VALUE3,FACTOR_VALUE4,FACTOR_VALUE5,FACTOR_VALUE6,FACTOR_VALUE7,WEIGHTING,START_DATE, END_DATE FROM ABC_PRICE_FACTOR WHERE ELEMENT_LOGIC_ID =? AND START_DATE <= ? AND END_DATE >= ? AND FACTOR_VALUE1=? ORDER BY ID DESC )) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1) ) 

    union 

    select ? as FACTORNAME,WEIGHTING,? as KEYCYCLE,? as KEYTRAVELLER,? as KEYSUBFORMULA from ( (SELECT * FROM ( (SELECT ID, ELEMENT_LOGIC_ID, FACTOR_VALUE1, FACTOR_VALUE2,FACTOR_VALUE3,FACTOR_VALUE4,FACTOR_VALUE5,FACTOR_VALUE6,FACTOR_VALUE7,WEIGHTING,START_DATE, END_DATE FROM ABC_PRICE_FACTOR WHERE ELEMENT_LOGIC_ID =? AND START_DATE <= ? AND END_DATE >= ? AND FACTOR_VALUE1>? ORDER BY ID DESC )) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1) ) 

    union 

    select ? as FACTORNAME,WEIGHTING,? as KEYCYCLE,? as KEYTRAVELLER,? as KEYSUBFORMULA from ( (SELECT * FROM ( (SELECT ID, ELEMENT_LOGIC_ID, FACTOR_VALUE1, FACTOR_VALUE2,FACTOR_VALUE3,FACTOR_VALUE4,FACTOR_VALUE5,FACTOR_VALUE6,FACTOR_VALUE7,WEIGHTING,START_DATE, END_DATE FROM ABC_PRICE_FACTOR WHERE ELEMENT_LOGIC_ID =? AND START_DATE <= ? AND END_DATE >= ? AND FACTOR_VALUE1<? AND FACTOR_VALUE2=? ORDER BY ID DESC )) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1) ) 

    union 

    ...

    )
```

note:
dynamically bellow part is different in the query. It is depending on factor match type [equal, lower bound, upper bound]. there are 7 factors. FACTOR_VALUE1,FACTOR_VALUE2.... like wise. So I am not going to show you actual SQL here. it has 1.8 MB query.

equal

```
FACTOR_VALUE1=?
```

or lower bound

```
FACTOR_VALUE1<?
```

or upper bound

```
FACTOR_VALUE1>?
```

**business logic behind the scene**

sorry guys for not providing actual and provide sample query. I am expecting a comment on my approach. 
It's like we have data of exam result.
there are 10 subjects in school.
there are 15 students.
there are 2 exam term tests.

those are in DB.

this data can be read in 2 ways.

1. read all data at once, and filter in application level.[large union query]
2. read one student's one term results at one by one.[small query]

all ideas are welcome.

[image: sample result]

Comment: I am sure that someone else will chip in, but your SQL does not look at all correct.  a) why do you have embedded `selects`, the inner most seems to be enough b) why have unions, you only seem to select from one table

Comment: One very complex query can be slower than many quick ones. Honestly, just parsing and finding a plan for a 1.8M SQL query is going to take a lot of time. You should be able to rewrite the query into something simpler and more efficient, though, rather than just combining selects with union.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could knock up a simple test case along with the associated logic that shows what you're trying to achieve. (I.e. maybe with 3 factor_value columns, not 7). I'm thinking something along the lines of "Here is a simplified set of data, here what I expect the output to look like, and <this> is the logic of how to get the output. Then we might be able to suggest a better query for you.

Comment: *"this data can be read in 2 ways"* Actually there is a third way: read all data at once, and filter in the SQL statement. Seriously, SQL is a very powerful language, and there will be a way to write a query which returns exactly the rows you need in a performative fashion. The trick is to understand how to work with a **set of data**. This is apparently harder than coding a loop which processes one thing (record, row, array element) at a time but is worth mastering because set operations are vastly more efficient than row by row processing.

Answer (score 3):

> " I thought logically reading all data at once has a lot of performance, But DB is getting stuck."

Up to a point. One database call will likely be more efficient in terms of network traffic. But the actual call you make executes **lots of queries** and glues them together with UNION: so there is no performance gain to be had if the main problem is the performance of the individual queries.

One obvious change you can make: use UNION ALL rather than UNION if the subqueries are exclusive, and save yourself some unnecessary sorts.

Beyond that, the logic of the subqueries looks suspect: you're hitting the same subset of rows each time, so you should consider using subquery factoring:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT ID, ELEMENT_LOGIC_ID, FACTOR_VALUE1, FACTOR_VALUE2,FACTOR_VALUE3,FACTOR_VALUE4,FACTOR_VALUE5,FACTOR_VALUE6,FACTOR_VALUE7,WEIGHTING,START_DATE, END_DATE 
     FROM ABC_PRICE_FACTOR 
     WHERE ELEMENT_LOGIC_ID =? AND START_DATE <= ? AND END_DATE >= ? 
)
select ? as FACTORNAME,WEIGHTING,? as KEYCYCLE,? as KEYTRAVELLER,? as KEYSUBFORMULA from (
  select weighting from ( 
     select weighting
     from cte
     where FACTOR_VALUE1=? 
     order by id desc )
  where rownum <= 1
  union all
  select weighting from ( 
     select weighting
     from cte
     where FACTOR_VALUE1>? 
     order by id desc )
  where rownum <= 1
  union all
  select weighting from ( 
     select weighting
     from cte
     where FACTOR_VALUE1<? AND FACTOR_VALUE2=?
     order by id desc )
  where rownum <= 1
...
)
```

Warning: tuning without understanding of the data volumes and distribution (skew), data structures or business rules  - i.e. what you're asking us to do - is a mug's game. We're just guessing here, and the best you can hope for is that one of those guesses is lucky.

Answer (score 2):

I think such a query can be optimized with quite a dramatic speed improvement. To achieve that, one must understand the logic behind it, though. On Stackoverflow, this is best done by providing a minimal example and some code.

Idea 1) - `START_DATE`, `END_DATE`

You've shown us only `?`, so we don't know if the `?` for the dates of all subqueries are the same. If so, you could filter down the table once in an initial step, without repeating the filtering 1500 times:

`WITH datefiltered AS (SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?)
   SELECT ... FROM datefiltered;`

Idea 2) - `UNION`

Your pattern of `UNION` a lot of subqueries `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... ORDER BY ...) WHERE rownum <=1` is unusual. That is not a bad thing in itself, but it is likely that the database engine is not optimized for unusual queries.

You are using `ORDER BY ID DESC)) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1`, that means you are searching for the newest(?) row in a category.

The traditional pattern is to find a column (or more, or even an expression) and partition the query by it:

```
SELECT id, col1, col2 
  FROM (
        SELECT id, col1, col2, 
               ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY mycategory ORDER BY ID DESC) as my_rank 
          FROM ABC
       )
 WHERE my_rank <= 1;
```

In your case, the category is likely much more complex, but you can put that in a big `CASE` statement that groups your data into your subqueries:

```
CASE WHEN factor1=xx AND factor2>yy THEN 'mycat1'
     WHEN factor3>zz AND factor2<yy THEN 'mycat2'
     etc
 END;
```

To put all three together would look like

```
SELECT id, col1, col2 
  FROM (
        SELECT id, col1, col2, 
               ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY mycategory ORDER BY ID DESC) as my_rank 
          FROM (
                SELECT id, col1, col2,
                       CASE WHEN factor...
                        END as mycategory
                  FROM ABC
                 WHERE start_date <= xx AND end_date >= yy
               )
       )
 WHERE my_rank <= 1;
```